# css full page background color without repeat applied for BODY tag

Tags: css, user-interface

I want to have a background that covers the full page .

I added `Style` to the `body` tag .

## ATTEMPT1 : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Laf16m61/)

By default, the background is repeated .
[image]

## ATTEMPT2 : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Laf16m61/1/)

When I added `background-repeat:no-repeat` ,There is no repeating but the color is not appeared on the full page .
[image]

## ATTEMPT3:

We add those properties :

```
-moz-background-size: cover;

-webkit-background-size: cover;

-o-background-size: cover;


    background-size: cover;
```

However , no new .

### Any idea : How to make the background color for full-page without repeating by applying a style to BODY tag ?

Comment: Yes background-size: cover. And background-position: center center. Your fiddle is an bad example. Add body { height: 800px; } to see that it worked with background-size: cover

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `height` for `<html>` and `<body>`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Laf16m61/4/)

```
.your_gradient_class {
    /* Your gradient declaration goes here */

    background-attachment: fixed; /* Add this */
}
```

I would recommend you to apply the gradient to the `<html>` instead of setting it to `<body>`

You might also want to take a look at `background-attachment: fixed;` which will be handy for your background.

Note that you don't have to use `background-size: cover;` for this.

Comment: This is the answer. something to consider adding to the `html, body` rule would be `padding: 0; margin: 0;` as you may get scroll bars otherwise.

Comment: @Raad That's the part of the reset so I expect he is doing that but thanks for adding that tip.

Comment: You're welcome - I didn't see the "normalize" option ticked on the fiddle, but did see the scroll bar, hence the tip =)

Comment: @Raad Yea I don't check those cuz if I do OP may feel it works well on fiddle but why not on local ... and if he has reseted already than it won't harm anyways hence ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-color`:

```
.color-grad {background-color: rgb(238,244,248);}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Laf16m61/3/

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of the gradient not extending over the full height of the browser window - it just masks it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve full body color without repetition by doing the following CSS. e.g

```
html, body{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(19, 51, 76, 5), rgba(0, 87, 146, 5));
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just set the body height to 100vh and the color wasn't again repeated.

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(253, 211, 0, 0.837), #fda900);
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello dear!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

}